Why does the click event work the first time, but subsequent clicks only affect in last DOM node?
issue
I encountered an issue while using D3.js. I have two functions, unexpectedCode and expectedCode, which are supposed to draw some circles in an SVG and change their color when clicked. The click event in expectedCode works fine, but in unexpectedCode, it only works the first time. Subsequent clicks only change the color of the last circle. I'm new to D3.js, and this is quite confusing for me. I would really appreciate it if you could help me analyze the problem!
core code
const unexpectedCode = (selection) => {
      selection
        .append("g")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(dots)
        .join((enter) => {
          enter
            .append("circle")
            .style("cursor", "pointer")
            .attr("id", (d) => "circle" + d)
            .attr("cx", (d) => d * 32)
            .attr("cy", 20)
            .attr("r", (d) => d * 5)
            .call((circle) => {
              circle.on("click", (e, d) => {
                console.log("d", d);
                enter
                  .select(`#circle` + d)
                  .transition()
                  .attr("fill", "red")
                  .transition()
                  .attr("fill", "black");
              });
            });
        });
    };
const expectedCode = (selection) => {
      selection
        .append("g")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(dots)
        .join((enter) => {
          enter
            .append("circle")
            .style("cursor", "pointer")
            .attr("id", (d) => "circle" + d)
            .attr("cx", (d) => d * 32)
            .attr("cy", 20 + yOffset)
            .attr("r", (d) => d * 5)
            .each((datum) => {
              enter.select(`#circle` + datum).call((circle) => {
                circle.on("click", () => {
                  circle
                    .transition()
                    .attr("fill", "red")
                    .transition()
                    .attr("fill", "black");
                });
              });
            });
        });
    };

reproduction
codesandbox
what I want
Explain the behavior or logic behind unexpectedCode.
new discovery
The issue seems to be with enter.select. You can try using this demo, but I still don't understand why. In my understanding, since I added  elements to enter, I should be able to find these circles within enter, and it should be faster than using d3.select. However, in reality, using enter.select, my code doesn't work correctly.
circle.on("click", (e, d) => {
  console.log("d", d);
  // use d3.select can work well
  // d3.select(`#circle` + d)
  //   .transition()
  //   .attr("fill", "red")
  //   .transition()
  //   .attr("fill", "black");
  enter
    .select(`#circle` + d)
    .transition()
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .transition()
    .attr("fill", "black");
});


I would normally suggest delegation but in this case it is more readable to bind the event handler immediately after appending the circle elements without re-selecting or iterating and more efficient because it avoids unnecessary re-selections (enter.select() inside .each()) and re-iterations over the data.
codesandbox
const fixedUnexpectedCode = (selection) => {
  selection
    .append("g")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(dots)
    .join((enter) => {
      const circle = enter
        .append("circle")
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .attr("id", (d) => "circle" + d)
        .attr("cx", (d) => d * 32)
        .attr("cy", 20)
        .attr("r", (d) => d * 5);

      // Attach click event directly to the circle selection
      circle.on("click", (e, d) => {
        console.log("d", d);
        d3.select(`#circle${d}`)
          .transition()
          .attr("fill", "red")
          .transition()
          .attr("fill", "black");
      });
    });
};


Yes, your code optimization suggestions are great, and writing it this way makes it clearer. However, code optimization is another topic. Now I have discovered that when I use d3.select to select elements within the circle's click event callback, instead of using enter.select, my unexpectedCode works correctly.

In my understanding, since I added  elements to enter, I should be able to find these circles within enter, and it should be faster than using d3.select. However, in reality, using enter.select, my code doesn't work correctly. This is very confusing to me. you can try this demo

I'm not sure I follow your code and event binding.  A more canonical way to do this with d3 would be:
const unexpectedCode = (selection) => {
  selection
    .append("g")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(dots)
    .join((enter) => {
      enter
        .append("circle")
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .attr("id", (d) => "circle" + d)
        .attr("cx", (d) => d * 32)
        .attr("cy", 20)
        .attr("r", (d) => d * 5)
        .on("click", function() {
          d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .attr("fill", "red")
            .transition()
            .attr("fill", "black");
        })
    });
};

